# generate binary list of minutes which indicates wheter or not said minute is in a given time range

Tags: numpy

I have a list of ranges that looks like this:

```
    [(Timestamp('2018-12-17 07:30:45', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-17 07:32:45', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-03 07:14:12', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-03 07:15:39', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-03 07:32:47', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-03 07:34:10', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-03 08:00:36', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-03 08:02:28', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:34:02', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:34:19', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:33:26', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:35:25', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:49:28', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:49:44', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:49:08', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-19 07:50:32', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-18 07:47:24', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-18 07:48:56', freq='S')),
 (Timestamp('2018-12-13 07:56:24', freq='S'),
  Timestamp('2018-12-13 07:57:58', freq='S'))]
```

The list goes from December 2018 to April 2019. Now I would like to create a list of integer values whose length is equal the number of minutes between that timespam, where the integer is 0, where the time is outside any of the timeranges and 1 if it is within one.
Basically for every minute of the timespam I want to be able discern wheter or not it is within any of the timeranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test purpose, I took a shorter set of date / time pairs:

```
arr = np.array([
    ('2018-12-17 23:40:45', '2018-12-17 23:45:45'),
    ('2018-12-18 00:14:12', '2018-12-18 00:20:39'),
    ('2018-12-18 00:30:47', '2018-12-18 00:34:10')], dtype='datetime64')
```

It is much easier to use *Pandas* to do your task and the code is more readable.

Start from conversion of *arr* into a *Pandas* DataFrame with 2 columns,
*time start* and *time end*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['tStart', 'tEnd'])
```

Then generate an *IntervalIndex*:

```
iInd = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.tStart, df.tEnd)
```

In the target version of code you will probably set the "border dates /
times" of the result to *0:00* at the start date and *23:59* at the end date,
but to keep the result as short as possible, I set them as time just before
the first interval and just after the last interval (rounded to minutes):

```
t1 = df.tStart.min().floor('min')
t2 = df.tEnd.max().ceil('min')
```

To create the result, I started with the "list of minutes" (a
*DatetimeIndex*):

```
mInd = pd.date_range(t1, t2, freq='min')
```

And the final step is to create the actual result:

```
result = pd.Series([iInd.contains(x).any() for x in mInd],
    index=mInd, dtype=int)
```

It is a *Series* with:

- consecutive minutes as the index,
- either *0* or *1* as values.

The result, for the assumed (shorter) list if intervals, is:

```
2018-12-17 23:40:00    0
2018-12-17 23:41:00    1
2018-12-17 23:42:00    1
2018-12-17 23:43:00    1
2018-12-17 23:44:00    1
2018-12-17 23:45:00    1
2018-12-17 23:46:00    0
2018-12-17 23:47:00    0
2018-12-17 23:48:00    0
2018-12-17 23:49:00    0
2018-12-17 23:50:00    0
2018-12-17 23:51:00    0
2018-12-17 23:52:00    0
2018-12-17 23:53:00    0
2018-12-17 23:54:00    0
2018-12-17 23:55:00    0
2018-12-17 23:56:00    0
2018-12-17 23:57:00    0
2018-12-17 23:58:00    0
2018-12-17 23:59:00    0
2018-12-18 00:00:00    0
2018-12-18 00:01:00    0
2018-12-18 00:02:00    0
2018-12-18 00:03:00    0
2018-12-18 00:04:00    0
2018-12-18 00:05:00    0
2018-12-18 00:06:00    0
2018-12-18 00:07:00    0
2018-12-18 00:08:00    0
2018-12-18 00:09:00    0
2018-12-18 00:10:00    0
2018-12-18 00:11:00    0
2018-12-18 00:12:00    0
2018-12-18 00:13:00    0
2018-12-18 00:14:00    0
2018-12-18 00:15:00    1
2018-12-18 00:16:00    1
2018-12-18 00:17:00    1
2018-12-18 00:18:00    1
2018-12-18 00:19:00    1
2018-12-18 00:20:00    1
2018-12-18 00:21:00    0
2018-12-18 00:22:00    0
2018-12-18 00:23:00    0
2018-12-18 00:24:00    0
2018-12-18 00:25:00    0
2018-12-18 00:26:00    0
2018-12-18 00:27:00    0
2018-12-18 00:28:00    0
2018-12-18 00:29:00    0
2018-12-18 00:30:00    0
2018-12-18 00:31:00    1
2018-12-18 00:32:00    1
2018-12-18 00:33:00    1
2018-12-18 00:34:00    1
2018-12-18 00:35:00    0
Freq: T, dtype: int32
```

If you need, you can convert it to a *Numpy* array, but I think a more readable
version is just as here, a *Series*.